# How to use recycler view with cursor loader and item animation in Android

Tags: android, cursor, android-recyclerview, android-cursorloader

I am using cursor loader in my activity to load products in an user's store and displaying it in a Recycler view using cursor. The Recycler view has multiple view types (three to be specific). The user has the ability to delete a product. When a user deletes a product, I set a flag in sqlite and the cursor loader notifies me about the change. However, I cannot change the visualization in the Recycler View accordingly. I tried swapping the cursor and using 'notifyDataSetChanged()' but it did not have any effect i.e. the view did not refresh. I understand that for animations to work I should delete an item and notify the adapter using notifyItemDeletedAt(position) but how do I achieve this with a cursor loader, where the only callback I get is a new cursor? The only solution I found right now is to write custom animation when delete is clicked and then initializing a new adapter when I receive a 'onLoadFinished()' callback and making it scroll to the last adapter's position. It leads to a jittery effect, though.

I am posting a snippet of the RecylerView Adapter below. How can I achieve smooth animation and view refresh in recycler view using cursor and cursor loader without having to initialize a new adapter and making use of the notifyItemDeletedAt() function.

```
private static final int TYPE_SHOPPERTS_PRODUCT = 1;
private static final int TYPE_SELF_PRODUCT = 2;
private static final int TYPE_SELF_COLLECTION = 3;

public AgentStoreProductsInCategoryAdapter(Activity iActivity, Cursor  iProductsCursor) {
    this.productsCursor = iProductsCursor;
    this.mActivity = iActivity;
    this.agentId = SystemPreferenceManager.getAgentId(iActivity.getApplicationContext());
}

// This code did not work for me
public void swapCursor(Cursor iNewCursor){
    this.productsCursor = iNewCursor;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

// root view holder - the three child view holders extend from this
public class ProductPreviewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View view;
    ImageView deleteProductButton;
    // MORE DECLERATIONS

    public ProductPreviewViewHolder(View iView){
        super(iView);
        this.view = iView;
        deleteProductButton = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
    }
}

public class ShoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder extends ProductPreviewViewHolder {
    DeleteProductListener deleteProductListener = new DeleteProductListener();
    // MORE DECLERATIONS

    public ShoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder(View iView) {
        super(iView);
        deleteProductButton.setOnClickListener(deleteProductListener);
        // MORE INITIALIZATIONS
    }
}

public class SelfProductPreviewViewHolder extends ProductPreviewViewHolder {

    DeleteProductListener deleteProductListener = new DeleteProductListener();
    // MORE DECLERATIONS

    public SelfProductPreviewViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        deleteProductButton.setOnClickListener(deleteProductListener);
        // MORE INITIALIZATIONS
    }
}

public class CollectionPreviewViewHolder extends ProductPreviewViewHolder {
    DeleteCollectionListener deleteCollectionListener = new DeleteCollectionListener();


    public CollectionPreviewViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        deleteProductButton.setOnClickListener(deleteCollectionListener);
        // MORE INITIALIZATIONS
    }
}

@Override
public ProductPreviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;
    switch (viewType){
        case TYPE_SHOPPERTS_PRODUCT:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_product_agent_store_shopperts, parent, false);
            return new ShoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder(itemView);
        case TYPE_SELF_PRODUCT:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_product_agent_store_self, parent, false);
            return new SelfProductPreviewViewHolder(itemView);
        case TYPE_SELF_COLLECTION:
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_collection_agent_store, parent, false);
            return new CollectionPreviewViewHolder(itemView);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    productsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    final int numProducts;
    if (productsCursor.getColumnIndex(
            ViewContract.AgentStoreCollectionView.COLUMN_NUM_PRODUCTS) != -1) {
        numProducts = productsCursor.getInt(productsCursor.getColumnIndex(
                ViewContract.AgentStoreCollectionView.COLUMN_NUM_PRODUCTS));
    } else {
        numProducts = 1;
    }
    int productSource = productsCursor.getInt(productsCursor.getColumnIndex(
            AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_SOURCE));

    if (productSource != agentId){
        return TYPE_SHOPPERTS_PRODUCT;
    } else {
        if (numProducts == 1) {
            return TYPE_SELF_PRODUCT;
        } else {
            return TYPE_SELF_COLLECTION;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    productsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    return productsCursor.getInt(productsCursor.getColumnIndex
            (AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry._ID));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductPreviewViewHolder holder, int position) {
    productsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    final int productId = productsCursor.getInt(productsCursor.getColumnIndex(
            AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID));

    if (holder instanceof ShoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder) {
        ShoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder shoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder =
                (ShoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder) holder;
        shoppertsProductPreviewViewHolder.deleteProductListener.updateData(productId,
                holder.view);

        // SOME MORE CODE

    } else if (holder instanceof SelfProductPreviewViewHolder) {
        SelfProductPreviewViewHolder selfProductPreviewViewHolder =
                (SelfProductPreviewViewHolder) holder;
        selfProductPreviewViewHolder.deleteProductListener.updateData(productId,
                holder.view);

        // SOME MORE CODE
    } else if (holder instanceof CollectionPreviewViewHolder){
        final CollectionPreviewViewHolder collectionPreviewViewHolder =
                (CollectionPreviewViewHolder) holder;
        collectionPreviewViewHolder.deleteCollectionListener.updateData(collectionId,
                holder.view);

        // SOME MORE CODE
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (productsCursor != null) {
        return productsCursor.getCount();
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}
// Custom code for slide_right when delete button is clicked and to update the database accordingly for deleting a collection
protected void removeCollection(final Context context, final View rowView, final int collectionId) {
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            context, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            rowView.clearAnimation();   // to get rid of flicker at end of animation
            rowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ContentValues storeEntry = new ContentValues();
            storeEntry.put(AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.COLUMN_DELETED,
                    Constants.DeletedStatus.DELETED);
            String where = AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.COLUMN_COLLECTION_ID + "=?";
            String args[] = new String[]{Integer.toString(collectionId)};
            context.getContentResolver().update(AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    storeEntry, where, args);
            SyncStoreIntentService.startActionSyncEntireStore(context);
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        }
    });
    rowView.startAnimation(animation);
}

// Custom code for slide_right when delete button is clicked and to update the database accordingly
protected void removeListItem(final Context context, final View rowView, final int productId) {
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            context, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            rowView.clearAnimation();   // to get rid of flicker at end of animation
            rowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ContentValues storeEntry = new ContentValues();
            storeEntry.put(AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.COLUMN_DELETED,
                    Constants.DeletedStatus.DELETED);
            String where = AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + "=?";
            String args[] = new String[]{Integer.toString(productId)};
            context.getContentResolver().update(AgentStoreContract.AgentStoreEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    storeEntry, where, args);
            SyncStoreIntentService.startActionSyncEntireStore(context);
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        }
    });
    rowView.startAnimation(animation);
}

// Listener for deleting a product
private class DeleteProductListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    int productId;
    View view;

    public void updateData(int iProductId, View iView){
        this.productId = iProductId;
        this.view = iView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (view != null) {
            removeListItem(v.getContext(), view, productId);
        }
    }
}

// Listener for deleting a collection
private class DeleteCollectionListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    int collectionId;
    View view;

    public void updateData(int iCollectionId, View iView){
        this.collectionId = iCollectionId;
        this.view = iView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (view != null) {
            removeCollection(v.getContext(), view, collectionId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the onLoadFinished() function

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    switch(loader.getId()) {
        case LOADER_PRODUCTS:
            int mScrollPosition = 0;
            if (layoutManager != null) {
                mScrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            }
            productsAdapter = new AgentStoreProductsInCategoryAdapter(
                    AgentStoreProductsInCollectionActivity.this,
                    data);
            productsRecyclerView.setAdapter(productsAdapter);
            productsRecyclerView.invalidate();
            mScrollPosition = mScrollPosition <= data.getCount() ? mScrollPosition : data.getCount();
            layoutManager.scrollToPosition(mScrollPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `CursorJoiner` to see the difference between two `Cursor`s

Comment: That's are a nice suggestion. I'll try it out. Any idea on the performance of cursor joiner? The cursor size in my case should not exceed 10,000.